# Errno2 no such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, sox

i've been trying to run sox in a python script but it can't the output file and gives me [errno2]

```
def AudioToSpectrogram(self, files, pixel_per_sec, height, width):

file_name = ("tmp_{}.png").format(random.randint(0, 100000))

command  = "sox -V0 {} -n remix 1 rate 10k spectrogram -y {} -x {} -X {} -m -r -o {}".format(files, height, width, pixel_per_sex, file_name)
p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)

Output, errors = p.communicate()
If errors:
   Print(errors)

Image = Image.open(file_name)
Os.remove(file_name)

Return np.array(image)
```

This is the error it gives

```
Exception: [errno2] No such file or Directory: 'tmp_47483.png'
```

I hope you could give me some pointers since i am still new in this field, thanks in advance!

Comment: show the full traceback otherwise the error message is quite clear

Comment: i can't show the full traceback since it only shows the Exception: [errno2] No such file or Directory: still thanks for responding my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `tmp_47483.png` is in fact being created, the problem is likely that the command is placing the file in a different folder and Python can't find it inside the current working directory. The

```
# manually set the full path (make sure the backslashes are escaped by putting two each)
file_name = f"C:\\Full\\Path\\To\\File\\tmp_{random.randint(0, 100000}.png"

# use the os module to join the path
base_dir = "C:\\Full\\Path\\To\\File"
file_name = os.path.join(base_dir, f"tmp_{random.randint(0, 100000}.png")

# if you want it to appear in the same folder as your script:
CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))    # mostly fool-proof way of getting a script's Current Working Directory
file_name = os.path.join(CWD, f"tmp_{random.randint(0, 100000}.png")
```

Try these and see if they help. If not, make sure that `command` is actually working and outputting a file somewhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answering my question, i done what you have told me and it works. but i have the problem when deleting the temporary file image.this is the error, [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

so i tried temporary solution by commenting out the os.remove(file_name). is there anyway to fix it? thank you so much btw for your help. i really appreciate it.

Comment: @NurSumusod that's probably because you're opening the image right above that line, so you can't delete it yet. Assuming you're using PIL, you need to do `Image.close()` before you can do `os.remove()`. Try seeing if you can save `np.array(image)` to a variable, then close the image, then delete the file _then_ return the `np,array` variable you saved.